# glDrawPixels Access violation reading location

Tags: c++, opengl, rendering

I am trying to render volumetric data using OpenGL function `glDrawPixels()`

```
#define SIZE    480
unsigned int    rgbPixels[SIZE][SIZE]
...
glDrawPixels(SIZE, SIZE, GL_RGB, GL_UNSIGNED_INT, rgbPixels);
```

If I do `sizeof(rgbpixels)` it returns 921600 which is what 480*480*4.

I have tried `GL_RGBA` but does no good. Finally I got something on the screen without getting access violation using `glDrawPixels(SIZE, SIZE*0.81, GL_RGB, GL_UNSIGNED_INT, rgbPixels);`

But it is not as per my expected output. So can anyone help me in this case?

Comment: What type is `rgbPixels`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are telling `glDrawPixels` that your data is `SIZExSIZE` pixels and each pixel has 3 components (`GL_RGB`) of 32-bit unsigned integer type **each** (`GL_UNSIGNED_INT`). If this is not the case for `rgbPixels` (which probably isn't when you say it's just `SIZE*SIZE*4` instead of the required `SIZE*SIZE*3*4`), then this will likely result in an access violation or other undefined behaviour.

When you say your `rgbPixels` is of size `SIZE*SIZE*4`, then I guess each pixel contains 4-bytes, with each individual byte being one color component. If this is the case you need

```
glDrawPixels(SIZE, SIZE, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, rgbPixels);
```

Just always keep in mind that all the parameters of `glDrawPixels` tell the OpenGL how much memory the pointer argument (`rgbPixels`) uses and in which format it is layed out. So those of course have to match the actual memory that `rgbPixels` contains (or points to).

Comment: you are awesome.. dont know how i missed that.. wasted 3 continuous hours

Comment: And I would also add :"Why on earth do you use drawPixels() in the first place?". ;)

Comment: yeah I know it is slow.. but is there any other option to draw image on screen? I am rendering volumetric data, reading from a file and drawing images repetitively

Comment: @Adorn Yes, just draw a texture mapped onto a screen-sized quad. In fact modern OpenGL (3+ core) doesn't have `glDrawPixels` anymore.

Answer (score 1):

As given the OpenGL will expect 3 unsigned integers per pixel! You probably want to use `GL_UNSIGNED_INT_8_8_8_8` instead as the data type.